# changing attribute of input date min date after being loaded using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

so after i load the form that contains the html5  i need to modify its minimum date so i tried this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#JQTarget").load("Forms.php #Renew"), function(){
            $("#JQTarget").find("#startDate").attr({"min" : '2013-12-09'});
}
            });
```

i also tried this but still didn't work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#JQTarget").load("Forms.php #Renew").ready( function(){
            $("#JQTarget").find("#startDate").attr({"min" : '2013-12-09'});
});
            });
```

so any idea ?
i also tried not using find at all and just use $("#startDate") but it didn't work
it does not seem to return the right element actually what gets returned isn't even html so idk what is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Format of the date is not correct. It should be YYYY-MM-DD:

```
.attr({"min" : '2013-12-09'});
```

Answer (score 0):

div with #jQTarget Also in your example the find selector is looking for an element startDate, not an element with an id #startDate (just in case you didn't notice when you applied the fix from dfsq).

**Edit: This works for me...**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
//note that the function callback is part of the load method so don't close the parens 
//after passing in the thing to load -> that was the mistake in the first example you listed. 

    $('#JQTarget').load('Forms.php #Renew', function() {
        $('#startDate').attr('min' , '2013-12-09');
    });

});
```

Assuming that your page has an element with an id of JQTarget and your Forms.php has a div that somehow resembles this:

```
<div id="Renew">
    <form>
        <input type="date" name="startdate" id="startDate" min="2000-01-02">
    <form>
</div>
```

...should work for you too.

Comment: yea i actually fixed that too but forgot to edit didn't work either

Comment: Are you not getting the #startDate returned? or are you just not able to update the attribute?  If it's the latter, maybe try to simplify your first example, by just passing the attribute name and value like this: .attr("min", "2013-12-09").

Comment: Ty man big time so the problem was that i didn't put min atr in input html i thought it would still work so the jquery wasn't the problem but ur jquery works too thx alot